# How can i do a Android Program with WebView and progress bar with custom error message

Tags: java, android, error-handling, webview, progress-bar

I have tried to link a webpage in an android app with webview and set a progress bar, and display the custom error message when page is not available, It works fine but error message is not get displayed, any one help me.

```
package com.arun.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Sample extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_students_login);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view,int errorCode ,String description,String failingUrl)
        {
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
        }
    });
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.co.in");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

}

    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

             @Override
             public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

              super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
              findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             }



            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting webview client twice. Remove the first one.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
```

and move  onReceivedError to  myWebViewClient

```
 @Override
  public void onReceivedError
```